# How to verify a toggle button state?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert the exercises of this book [Microsoft Visual Basic 2013 Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667047) to Visual C#, however on page 206 there's a small piece of code that I'm struggling to convert to C#. Anyone here could help me translate this if statement to C#?

```
If DisplayToggleBtn.IsChecked Then         
AutumnImage.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
Else
AutumnImage.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
End If
```

Comment: How do you have converted it and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

it should be the slimier

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

if (DisplayToggleBtn.IsChecked) {
    AutumnImage.Visibility  =  Visibility.Visible
else {
    AutumnImage.Visibility  =  Visibility.Collapsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

if (DisplayToggleBtn.IsChecked.HasValue && DisplayToggleBtn.IsChecked.Value) {
    AutumnImage.Visibility  =  Visibility.Visible
else {
    AutumnImage.Visibility  =  Visibility.Collapsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

even slimier

```
AutumnImage.Visibility = DisplayToggleBtn.IsChecked ? 
                         Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```